# JavaScript code reading order with multiple assignment operators

Tags: javascript, operators, variable-assignment

I got this simple piece of code:

```
var x=10;
var y=8;
 x -= y += 9;


alert(x+" and "+y);
```

The result will be "-7 and 17".

Why does JavaScript executes the y +=9 before the x -= y?

Comment: Because `-=` and `+=` are [right associative operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) and this are evaluated right-to-left.

Comment: You can check the order on [astexplorer.net](https://astexplorer.net/#/gist/002e8247e6a15ed12a5062d9d19acfa8/d5a9b8ef5b605682951257d4b7df7803640deaf1). Expand the expression on the right side panel to see the order

Comment: @vlaz stop answering in the comments! ;)

Comment: @JonasWilms is there not a canonical for all things to do with precedence? I don't want to answer this question then find out somebody asked a different one that is still simply "how are operators evaluated".

Comment: @vlaz not that I know of ... And you already gave a good answer (as a comment), so there would be no harm from posting that as an answer. (with the positive side effect that you get closer to a js gold badge, and I no longer have to dupe hammer your suggestions ;))

Answer (score 1):

Operator precedence determines the way in which operators are parsed with respect to each other. Operators with higher precedence become the operands of operators with lower precedence

Associativity determines the way in which operators of the same precedence are parsed.

Since `-= and +=` are right associative therefore they are evaluated from right to left.

Hence `y +=9` gets evaluated first.

[Reference Link for operators](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_10.0.0/reference/r_wpdr_elements_operators_r.html)